# Granger Causality: Alternative Hypothesis for VAR

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I know that if ALL the coefficients on the lagged values of, say, $y_2$ are $0$ in the equation for $y_1$, then $y_2$ fails to Granger cause $y_1$. Therefore, our null hypothesis for  Granger causality for a VAR model is that all the aforementioned coefficients are $0$

But now, I am confused about the alternative hypothesis, where we prove that $y_2$ Granger causes $y_1$. Does $y_2$ Granger cause $y_1$ if:

1. NONE of the aforementioned coefficients are $0$, or
2. AT LEAST ONE  of the aforementioned coefficients is NOT $0$

Comment: AT LEAST ONE of the aforementioned coefficients is NOT 0.